# It is bullying to mock

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

'It is bullying to mock a foreign speaker’s accent. No one deserves to be laughed at for their pronunciation.'

I　don't quite understand why bullying (present participle) is used. I don't think it is the present continuous tense. Or, is bullying a gerund here? Can someone help with it? Thank you.

Comment: It might sound more logical to you if it were written like this: _Mocking a foreign speaker's accent is bullying._

Answer (score 2):

Bullying is a noun here. Compare:

> *It is a mistake to mock a foreign speaker's accent.*

The noun *bully* denotes a person, so *bullying* is used to name the act with a meaning similar to *intimidation*.

[Merriam Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullying)

> bullying
>
> noun
>
> abuse and mistreatment of someone vulnerable by someone stronger, more powerful, etc. : the actions and behavior of a bully